# fabric js add handler rotate on custom html element

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Im trying add handler on the html element

```
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    _drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
        if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(control);
        var size = this.cornerSize;
        if(control !== 'mtr')   ctx['fillRect'](left, top, size, size);
        if(control === 'mtr') {
            var self = this;
            console.log(self);
        }
    }
});
```

Im finding function drawControl but i know't how i can add this event on my button.

> P.S. Forgive knowledge of English and a javascript at an average level, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: you can change angle of object instead

Comment: Yeah, i know.
but I want to link all the events that are on the button being created, that is, the possibility of rotating the drag-n-drop -th rotation along with the element, etc.

Comment: something like [this](http://fabricjs.com/controls)

Comment: I want to copy the behavior of the standard handler on custom btn. [What i have](https://prnt.sc/m054ia). I'll readed documentation and found nothing =(